# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drop' in pandas when used drop() function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, drop

prerequisites:

these are  all the columns in my "movies" dataframe:

```
Index(['color', 'director_name', 'num_critic_for_reviews', 'duration',
       'director_facebook_likes', 'actor_3_facebook_likes', 'actor_2_name',
       'actor_1_facebook_likes', 'gross', 'genres', 'actor_1_name',
       'movie_title', 'num_voted_users', 'cast_total_facebook_likes',
       'actor_3_name', 'facenumber_in_poster', 'plot_keywords',
       'movie_imdb_link', 'num_user_for_reviews', 'language', 'country',
       'content_rating', 'budget', 'title_year', 'actor_2_facebook_likes',
       'imdb_score', 'aspect_ratio', 'movie_facebook_likes'],
      dtype='object')
```

code:

```
movies = movies.drop(['color', 'duration',
       'director_facebook_likes', 'actor_3_facebook_likes', 'actor_2_name',
       'actor_1_facebook_likes',
        'cast_total_facebook_likes',
       'actor_3_name', 'facenumber_in_poster',
       'movie_imdb_link',
       'content_rating', 'actor_2_facebook_likes',
        'aspect_ratio','plot_keywords'],axis = 1,inplace = True,errors = 'ignore')
```

error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-9e237d43e9bd> in <module>
      1 # Check the 'drop' function in the Pandas library - dataframe.drop(list_of_unnecessary_columns, axis = )
      2 # Write your code for dropping the columns here. It is advised to keep inspecting the dataframe after each set of operations
----> 3 movies = movies.drop(labels = ['color', 'duration',
      4        'director_facebook_likes', 'actor_3_facebook_likes', 'actor_2_name',
      5        'actor_1_facebook_likes',

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'drop'
```

Comment: `movies` is a `None`. Not enough information to find out, why.

Comment: I had edited the problem !!

Comment: inplace=True drops the columns and saves the dataframe. you need not reassign the result to movies.

Comment: if I also remove that assignment ,It is giving the same error